# How to customize Ionic 2 Slider

Tags: ionic2

I'm working in Ionic 2, I have used Ionic 2 `Slider` and I attached Ionic reference [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) which I used.

I have developed this but, 
my requirement is both side 10 percent `Slider` should be show
**see second one image this is my requirement,**
so how can i customize it 
Please help me

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specifik about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @robbannn I believe he wants to show the image before, and the image after for 10% on the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width:80%` so it will work properly

```
.slides  { 
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using CSS only:

```
.slides  { 
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-container{
    overflow: inherit !important;
}
.swiper-slide {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```